# Collections and Nested Attribute Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Assume I have the models Foo and Bar, where Bar is a nested attribute of Foo.

```
<%= form_for @foo do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :bars do |builder| %>
   <%= render 'bar_fields', :f => builder %>
 <% end %>  
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The partial bar_fields has the fields that correspond to the attributes in Bar. I only want to edit certain fields in this model, so I've left out these out. Instead I want to output the values of these fields as text and to be able to access their ActiveRecord relations.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access object variables from a form helper do:

```
f.object.your_variable
```